# UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout center items in group

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I've got a collection view using a `UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout`. It's rendering 8 cells in a two-column grid. The cell's should self-size according to their content which can vary in length.

Here's what I've got:

[image: Screenshot from the View Hierarchy Debugger]

The issue here is on the second cell (top right). It's of the correct size but it's aligned to the top edge instead of being centered inside its group. And it looks bad.

So, my question is: **How do I align items to the center of their group?**

For reference, here's my layout code:

```swift
private lazy var layout: UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout = {
    let spacing: CGFloat = 10

    let itemSize = NSCollectionLayoutSize(widthDimension: .fractionalWidth(1),
                                          heightDimension: .estimated(60))
    let item = NSCollectionLayoutItem(layoutSize: itemSize)

    let groupSize = NSCollectionLayoutSize(widthDimension: .fractionalWidth(1),
                                           heightDimension: .estimated(60))
    let group = NSCollectionLayoutGroup.horizontal(layoutSize: groupSize, subitem: item, count: 2)
    group.interItemSpacing = .fixed(spacing)

    let section = NSCollectionLayoutSection(group: group)
    section.interGroupSpacing = spacing

    return UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout(section: section)
}()
```

And here's the cell's constraints:

```swift
private lazy var imageView: UIImageView = {
    let imageView = UIImageView()
    imageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
    imageView.clipsToBounds = true
    return imageView
}()

private lazy var descriptionLabel: UILabel = {
    let label = UILabel()
    label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    label.font = UIFont.preferredFont(forTextStyle: .caption1)
    label.textColor = .label
    label.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.left
    label.numberOfLines = 0
    return label
}()

private func setup() {
    contentView.addSubview(imageView)
    contentView.addSubview(descriptionLabel)

    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
        imageView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.layoutMarginsGuide.leadingAnchor),
        imageView.topAnchor.constraint(greaterThanOrEqualTo: contentView.layoutMarginsGuide.topAnchor),
        imageView.bottomAnchor.constraint(lessThanOrEqualTo: contentView.layoutMarginsGuide.bottomAnchor),
        imageView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.centerYAnchor),
        imageView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: imageView.widthAnchor),
        imageView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 33),

        descriptionLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalToSystemSpacingAfter: imageView.trailingAnchor, multiplier: 1),
        descriptionLabel.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: imageView.centerYAnchor),
        descriptionLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.layoutMarginsGuide.topAnchor),
        descriptionLabel.bottomAnchor.constraint(lessThanOrEqualTo: contentView.layoutMarginsGuide.bottomAnchor),
        descriptionLabel.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.layoutMarginsGuide.trailingAnchor)
    ])
}
```

Comment: Did you find a solution to this problem?

Comment: No, sorry, I didn't find a way yet…